# Application instances in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have created an Application in Codeigniter which list courses on a web interface, let users register via mobile app, see or download free courses, pay for the paid categories to watch or download courses listed in that category. So far it works like a charm. My manager suddenly landed on this thread [Two application instance in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550060/two-application-instance-in-codeigniter) and has now come up with an idea that we should separate users for each categories and platforms. What our management is currently insisting is that copy and paste each installation in different sub-folders, copy databases, flush old data, change path variables and database name and fire up each app individually.

You can imagine for a developer how hard it is to digest this kind of solution. I want to ask, if there is a way to instantiate complete CI application by creating some mother class and than passing some parameters to constructors like categories ids etc and do things dynamically. Is it possible to create instances of entire Codeigniter application?

Comment: Why two application folder ? Create admin class in core,(extends CI controller) and create admin folder in controller. Now all new controller from admin folder will be extend from core admin class.
You can hadle assets and view in different folders (as we can call it in controller)